# Eclipse ADT Plugin wrong MD5 checksum ADT-23.0.4.zip

Tags: android, adt

I downloaded the latest Eclipse ADT Plugin ADT-23.0.4.zip, checked the MD5 checksum, and found that it did not match the published checksum. I repeated the download/check checksum process about 5 times, and even used three different MD5 checker tools, and always got the same result.

I downloaded from:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Published MD5 checksum: 91a43dcf686ab73dec2c08b77243492b

My MD5 Checksum: e6160e1a4e2e6b8ac5c9dada3a1f2ea4

Additionally the size of the file seems to be slightly different:
Published size:     103336810 bytes

My local file size: 103351808 bytes (File Properties:file size - not file size on disk)

As I said, I downloaded this file about 5 times, both by clicking the file link in Firefox, and by using a separate file downloader.

Although it seems to me that the online file is corrupt, I may be wrong.

I googled the MD5 checksum I get: e6160e1a4e2e6b8ac5c9dada3a1f2ea4 and there was only one result:
http://www.panc.cc/info/171ljo/

The site is not in English, so I'm not sure what it's all about, but it seems to offer the same file ADT-23.0.4.zip for download, but instead of quoting the same MD5 checksum as in the Android Developer site, it quotes the same checksum as I get.

I believe it's not safe to install this file in Eclipse, but maybe I'm missing something.  Has anyone experienced the same problem with this file?

Comment: Yes, me too. My MD5 checksum is same as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I getting the same problem with you. My MD5 checksum is `e6160e1a4e2e6b8ac5c9dada3a1f2ea4`. But for the security reason i'm prefer to install ADT plugin from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/. ADT Plugin zip file is a last choice if you unable download from Google ADT plugin site.

Comment: Actually, for some reason I can't get Eclipse to install the plugin properly from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ this is why I resort to downloading the zip file. I have this problem only with ADT plugin right from the beginning. I've spend many hours to get it to work with Kepler, and it wouldn't.  Now it doesn't work for me on Luna either. Very strange behavior of Eclipse...

Comment: I was reporting this issue to Google like your description above [https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81286], i hope this help you for future.